# Doughnut Chart with transparent range and point marker in charts.js and angulaJS

Tags: css, angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart, angular-chartist.js

I have an doughnut chart in angularJS prepaired using angular-charts.js. I need to add a transparent range in the graph (the range should take the color of the background. Also I need to add a marker in the graph at a particular point). Can this be done using charts.js a[image]nd angular.

Comment: Have a screenshot of what you mean by marker? Cheers!

Comment: Hello, I added the screen short, actually I need to add a transparent range for the white color (The range should take the color of the back ground. Also I need to add a marker on the chart (marked in with black marker).